# jquery animation on child of this selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have used `this` selector to animate an image in the `li` and `a` element

Jquery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".jcarousel-skin-tango  li").mouseenter(function () {
                jQuery(this).children("a").children("img").animate({
                    top: '10px'
                }, 2000);
            });
 });
```

html

```
 <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li>
                <a href="http://google.com/">
                    <img alt="" src="item1.gif" /><span>adfadf</span></a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

image no have any effet on moues enter , why ?

Comment: You didn't close the ready function.

Comment: `jQuery(this).children("a").children("img").css("border", "dashed 2px")` Works , just `animate` method has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the `img` needs to have the css `position` attribute set to either `relative` or `absolute` in order to respond to the `top` attribute, i.e:

```
#mycarousel img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Secondly, an elegant way to select a child element with jQuery is:

```
jQuery('img', this);
```

I have demonstrated this in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fPMUR/

Answer (score 1):

This  is short and also should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery(".jcarousel-skin-tango  li").mouseenter(function () {
          jQuery("img" , this).animate({
                top: '10px'
          }, 2000);
     });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7H7y9/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to animate a property that depends of the type of position of that element. Try  with `margin-top` or `padding-top` instead of `top` or add `position: absolute` to the image.

Working demo with padding-top [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JJXKR/).